# Splunk query - Total or Count by field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am working with event logs which contain many fields. I am trying to isolate 1 field and get a count of the value of that field and display the count in an existing table as a new field

This is my log:
`LOG_LEVEL="INFO" MESSAGE="Type_of_Call = Sample Call LOB = F DateTime_Stamp = 2022-10-10T21:10:53.900129 Policy_Number = 12-AB-1234-5 Requester_Id = A1231301 Last_Name = SAMPLE State = IL City = Chicago Zip 12345"  APPLICATION_VERSION="appVersion_IS_UNDEFINED"`

This is my splunk query:

```
| stats count, values(*) as * by Requester_Id 
| table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip
```

The issue that this query has is that it is grouping the Requester Id field into 1 row and not displaying the count at all.

This is what the table and the issue look like : [image]

What I want is that I need to make the rows unique and display the count of the Requester Id in a new field.

For example: if there are 2 logs with the same Requester_Id with value "abc", I would still display those two logs separately in a table because it would have other fields different such as the date and time but I would like to display the count of the Requester_Id as 2 in a new field in the same table.

updated picture of the total: [image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what the final result is to look like (a mock-up might help), but can say the count field is not shown because it's not part of the `table` command.

Comment: OMG that worked, I am such an idiot. Adding the Count in the table actually worked. Thank you so much. Do you know how I would display the Total for every field?

Comment: "Total" implies adding numbers, but the sample data is not numeric.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the count for the logs, Like how many log events happened? Each row is an event, In the screenshot above there are 3 events. Basically I want to display that 3 event in a new field called total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the count field to the `table` command.

To get the total count at the end, use the `addcoltotals` command.

```
| table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip count
| addcoltotals labelfield=Type_of_Call label="Total Events" count
```

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: `| stats count as Total_by_Requester values(*) as * by Requester_Id 
| table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip Total_by_Requester 
| addcoltotals labelfield=Type_of_Call label="Total Events" count` This is what I tried, But it didn't display the Total Events or the value of the total events in the new field in the table

Comment: The count field is missing from `table`.

Comment: `| stats count as Total_by_Requester values(*) as * by Requester_Id 
| table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip Total_by_Requester count 
| addcoltotals labelfield=Type_of_Call label="Total Events" count` I did add it in, Still no results in that field

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the table in the post above

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot.  I missed the rename of count to Total_by_Requester.  Try this code: `| stats count as Total_by_Requester values(*) as * by Requester_Id  | table Type_of_Call LOB DateTime_Stamp Policy_Number Requester_Id Last_Name State City Zip Total_by_Requester | addcoltotals labelfield=Type_of_Call label="Total Events" Total_by_Requester`

Comment: That worked, I can't thank you enough. I really appreciate all the help. Thank you